# arquivo php aparecendo em todas as páginas

Tags: php, magento

Eu preciso que um código php apareça em todas as páginas do meu site MAGENTO. Já tentei diversos caminhos inclusive utilizando o stack overflow em inglês mas sem sucesso.

Se eu coloco o php dentro do rodapé em CONFIGURACOES - VISUAL, ele não faz a leitura do código.

Como proceder?
Muito obrigado.
Luciano.

Comment: Consegue ser mais claro? Que tipo de código PHP você deseja que apareça em todas as páginas? Qual é a estrutura de arquivos da sua aplicação?

Answer (score 0):

Insira o seu código no phtml em:

*app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml*

OU

*app/design/frontend/seutema/seutema/template/page/html/head.phtml*